# DOM Manipulation in Promise `then` is not occurring after successful AJAX call in previous `then`

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I am in the middle of refactoring a large JS class, (which leans heavily on jQuery), and have switched the mess of callbacks, variables and tightly intertwined code into a series of promise chains that carry out the required changes in, each triggered by different user actions that fire events.

The script is for a modal on a page of HTML game links. The part of it I am having an issue with does does, in order:

1. Listens for a 'play game' button to be pressed.
2. Pulls information about the game from the button's data-attributes.
3. Opens a modal with a loading animation.
4. Conditionally uses some of that information to GET a correct user token from the API for that service.
5. Conditionally uses some of that information to POST to another API for the service that serves the games themselves. The response object contains a URL to the game itself.
6. Replace an iframe `src` attribute with that URL, shuts off the loading animation , and displays the iframe.

All the relevant information - the urls, the codes, tokens, titles etc. - are held in an object called `state`. Each function used in the chain of promises takes this state object as its only argument, and returns a modified version. Generally, it will have a single side effect (normally a DOM update). The updates have to happen in sequential order, and currently I have split every discrete action into a separate function whilst debugging (the `updateState` function is effectively `Object.assign` + some logging):

```
function gameSetupHandler(e, state) {
  const eventData = rejectEmptyProps($(e.target).data());
  const isDemo = $(e.target).hasClass(state.demoTriggerClass);
  Promise.resolve(resetState(state))
         .then(getPlayerTokenAndId) // AJAX request 1 (#4 in above list)
         .then(disableGameLoadButtons)
         .then(state => updateState(state, eventData, { isDemo }))
         .then(setModalGameState)
         .then(calculateAspectRatio)
         .then(calculateModalSize)
         .then(setupResizeHandler)
         .then(showModal)
         .then(getLaunchUrl) // AJAX request 2 (#5 in above list)
         .then(setGameSrc)
         .then(showGame)
         .catch(error => console.log(error.message));
}
```

An example of one of the simple functions:

```
function disableGameLoadButtons(state) {   $(state.loadGame).attr('disabled', true);   return state; }
```

Where I am having the issue in the second AJAX request. So the first AJAX request looks like this:

```
function getPlayerTokenAndId(state) {
  return Promise.resolve($.get('/api/Lobby/PlayerToken')
                          .done(response => {                             return updateState(state, { playerToken: response.GameToken, playerId: response.UserId });
                          })
                          .fail(() => alert(state.errorMsgToken)));
}
```

That works fine: the chaining continues, the state updates, the modal appears onscreen.

But the second request is more complex, and conditional:

```
function getLaunchUrl(state) {
  const player = {
    PlayerId: (state.isDemo) ? 0 : state.playerId,
    PlayerToken: (state.isDemo) ? 'demotoken' : state.playerToken,
    Currency: 'GBP',
    Channel: 'desktop',
    Language: 'EN',
    AutoLaunch: false,
    IsDemo: state.isDemo,
    SourceUrl: '',
    SourceArea: '',
    TableId: state.tableId,
    Technology: state.technology,
  };

  if (state.url !== 'gms') {
    const url = state.url.replace('{PLAYER_TOKEN}', state.playerToken).replace('{PLAYER_ID}', state.playerId);
    return updateState(state, { url: url });
  }

  return Promise.resolve($.ajax({
                  url: `/gamelaunch/v1/games/${state.softwareId}/launch`,
                  type: 'post',
                  contentType: 'application/json',
                  data: JSON.stringify(player),
                  headers: {
                    'X-Correlation-Token': uuid.v4(),
                    'X-Site-Code': state.siteCode,
                    'X-CSRF-Token': state.csrfToken
                  }
                })
                .done(response => updateState(state, { url: response.launchUrl }))
                .fail(() => {
                  gameCloseHandler(null, state);
                  alert(state.errorMsg);
                }));
}
```

This is followed in the chain by this:

```
function setGameSrc(state) {
  $(state.gameIframe).attr('src', state.url);
  return state;
}
```

I can view the state being updated  - that occurs fine. I get a game URL no problem in `gameModal.state` when I check the console logging. But then that `setGameSrc` function never seems to fire, and the game src is never added to the DOM, and the game is never shown. I don't get any errors caught either. I might be missing something stupid here, but I've been going back and forth, and can't see what it is I'm failing to do.

I'll post more code if anyone requests

Comment: You must not use `done`. Use `then` instead. And since you `Promise.resolve` anyway, better do it immediately than around jQuery methods.

Comment: Ha. Yeah, the jQuery API methods were just holdover while I ripped them out bit by bit. I can't test it immediately as need to wait about two hours for builds to catch up, but if it's just as simple as that then thank you. However, using `done` within the previous handler, the `getPlayerTokenAndId` function works with no issues whatsoever, so not sure if this is the problem.

Comment: Yes, I found that weird as well. Maybe the `response` of the first request is a `state`-like object?

Comment: Hmm, it does the exact same thing in the `done` - it returns `updateState` (which is a wrapper for `Object.assign`, therefore just returns an updated state object)

Comment: either resolve or reject, why you are doing everything at the same time ?

Comment: The function does resolve: it resolves a $.ajax POST to a value or a failure. I've massively simplified the overall code by just extracting a context object and just passing that through a pipeline; however, some of those pipeline functions have side effects that have to happen in a specific sequence, I don't have enough control over the rest of the codebase to simplify anything external, and the public interface for this has to be identical to what I'm replacing. At base level, I need to know why the side effects in the function that follows the `then`-wrapped $.ajax are not firing, that's it